# Rename worksheet based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have three worksheets in excel which I am using.

First page is where I put all the data so it can populate in sheet 2 and sheet 3.

Sheet 2 and 3 is what I am going to save as pdf.

My question, is there a vba code that will name sheet 2 with the value in cell `A1` with the letter "F" next to it and then page three with the cell value in A1 again but with the letter E next to it?

For e.g. cell `A1` has Joy Nice, worksheet 2 will be named Joy Nice-F and worksheet 3 will be named Joy Nice-E. And yes I am new to VBA and I love what it can do. Thank you.

Comment: The answer to your question is: Yes there is! Can you show what you have done so far and where you got stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick (you will need to adjust names as needed):

```
Sub rename_sheets()
Dim renameCell As Range
Dim mainWS As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

Set mainWS = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change as necessary. This is the page with the names you want to use
Set renameCell = mainWS.Range("A1")

' Change the sheet names below to match the name they are *before* the renaming
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = renameCell.Value & "-F"
Sheets("Sheet3").Name = renameCell.Value & "-E"

End Sub
```

Comment: BruceWayne, thank you.  I love it.  Thank you so much! I want to learn VBA, basic things on how to save spreadsheets as pdf, how to print, how to have a bunch of names create the same letters over and over but with different customer.  Any good book you can recommend that can help me with this?  Again thank you.

Comment: Hello, This macro works great but can I add more to it? for example, I need sheet 2 to be saved as pdf. Then I need another Pdf for sheet 3.

Comment: @jack - Sorry for the delay in replying to your first comment on the 15th -- Honestly, when I learned (and obviously still am), my "go to tools" are: Macro Recorder in Excel and Google.  I use these to make the best attempts I can, then when I'm stuck I'd come here and ask around. Also there's [Chip Pearson's site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/mainpage.aspx) which I used to frequent.

Comment: @jack - To your other comment, that's a new question altogether.  If the macro I posted worked for this specific question, you can mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark left of the post.  If you want to save as PDF, try turning on the macro recorder, saving as PDF, stop the recorder, then check the code it generated.